# Get - Request , to display results in Alert()

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to create an app that will send out a get request, then take the response and display it on the page,
this is part of my learning process, ultimately i would like to have the response be parsed and turned into
elements etc. but for now i am having trouble accessing the information within the response.
How can i alert() any of the results in the response?

the results of the script below ranged from undefined, to [object ojbect]

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var bbz;
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "jsonp",
cache: false,
url: "MyDomain - its defined and on the web",
success: function(response) {

bbz = response;

alert(bbz.length);
alert(bbz);
alert(bbz[0]);
 }
});


        </script>
```

Comment: I guess you're not responding with jsonp, You're returning html, so you dataType should be set to 'html' instead

Comment: It looks to me like you are expecting a JSON response...`bbz.length`. You'll want to set your `dataType` to `"json"`.

Comment: @ModS Try using `console.log(bbz)` instead of `alert()`. It will log much more information into your browser console.

Comment: @lix this is defining the way i want the response to be formatted or the response i will be expecting?  Like will the server cater to my needs and send html if thats what i want, or will it send however it is stored?  sorry if im being confusing

Comment: It will define how you are expecting to get the response.

Comment: @uby Will that work with firebug or do i have to add Unsecure window @ the top some where? just asking because ive been through that bevfore.

Comment: @ModS it works like a charm: http://getfirebug.com/logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are expecting a JSON response...

I am assuming this because of the way you are accessing properties of the response object -

```
bbz = response;
alert(bbz.length);
```

You'll want to set your `dataType` to `"json"`.

Comment: @zac - no, "ultimately i would like to have the response be parsed and turned into elements". OP wants to (in the future), parse the response to create elements. The response itself contains just data.

Comment: in actuality im not 100% what i need i just have prior html css javascript and minor php knowledge, and would like to create an instagram api site. im having trouble getting data back and fourth and i got stuck with get / post because i didnt use that much prior.  @ZacharyKniebel

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `dataType` property to `html`, you should be able to simply return HTML.

You set `dataType: "jsonp"` which attempts to parse a `jsonp` object out of the data that is to be returned. However, what you really want is the markup that is in the file you are requesting data from. In order to do this, you must state the correct return type, so that the AJAX knows what data to give you, i.e. you tell the AJAX how to parse the data.

Comment: Don't just "get rid of" the property - set it to what it should be. Also defining a dataType will not change type of returned object - only how jQuery decided to parse the response. Exactly what is returned is defined by the server and not the client.

Comment: @Lix - I know what the property does, but perhaps I was unclear in my explanation. Also, I was wrong about the default setting for `dataType`. I will update my response.

Comment: I still have a problem with the line that says `"...which attempts to return a jsonp object to you"` The object that is returned is the same no matter what. The difference is that the setting tells jQuery how to behave with regard to the response.

Comment: I'm not saying that you don't know what the property does.. I'm just saying that there is no room for ambiguity here. Especially when dealing with a not too experienced user.

Comment: @Lix - Sorry, I forgot to update that part. I didn't mean to sound argumentative or defensive - I'm glad to get your feedback, as the goal here is to help educate, and the more feedback we receive from each other, the closer we get to achieving our goal :)

Comment: Well I'm always happy to *give* feedback :P It's a win-win ;)